# request mapping issue - spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, request-mapping

I am facing an issue with the request mapping in [spring-mvc](/questions/tagged/spring-mvc) as:
There are two url by which I am able to see the response of `uploadPage.jsp`

1. `http://localhost:8080/dms/files/?module=abc`
2. `http://localhost:8080/dms/files?module=abc`

The form in `uploadPage.jsp` is successfully submitted for the url **1** and the url in browser displayed as `http://localhost:8080/dms/files/upload`.
But for the url **2** there is an error with the browser url as `http://localhost:8080/dms/upload`.

What is the problem with this url mapping?

**Controller**:

```
package dms.spring.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import dms.pojo.CrmDms;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/files")
public class FileUploadController
{
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index( HttpServletRequest webRequest, ModelMap map )
    {
        String module = webRequest.getParameter( "module" );
        CrmDms crmDms = new CrmDms();
        crmDms.setModule( module );
        map.put( CrmDms.class.getSimpleName(), crmDms );
        return "uploadPage";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String uploadFile( @ModelAttribute(value = "CrmDms") CrmDms crmDms,
                              @RequestParam(value = "document") MultipartFile file,
                              ModelMap modelMap )
    {
        System.out.println( crmDms.getModule() );
        return "successPage";
    }
}
```

**JSP** (*uploadPage.jsp*):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="sf"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main-wrapper">
    <sf:form action="upload" method="post" commandName="CrmDms">
      <sf:input path="module" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </sf:form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Those are 2 different resource `/files` isn't `/files/`. The problem is that you are using relative URLs in your `action` attribute instead of `absolute` URLs. Use absolute URLs instead. You should post to `/dms/files/upload` and not `upload`. Use the URL tag (either spring or plain) to create the correct URL. `<sf:url value="/files/upload" var="actionUrl" />` then in your form element use `action="${actionUrl}"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a common problem with relative URLs in JSP. That's the reason why the rule is generally to always use absolute URLs.

When you first use `http://localhost:8080/dms/files/?module=abc`, the `<sf:form action="upload" method="post" ...` posts as expected to `http://localhost:8080/dms/files/upload` and is correctly processed by your controller.

But when you use `http://localhost:8080/dms/files?module=abc`, the `<sf:form action="upload" method="post" ...` posts to `http://localhost:8080/dms/upload` and gives you the error.

If you want to get rid of that problem, the simplest way is to use an absolute URL in `<sf:form` tag, either prepending context path *by hand* :

```
<sf:url var="upload" value="/files/upload"/>
<sf:form action="${upload}" method="post" commandName="CrmDms">
```

or by using (Spring > 3.2.3) the `servletRelativeAction` attribute :

```
<sf:form servletRelativeAction="/files/upload" method="post" commandName="CrmDms">
```

Comment: `servletRelativeAction` seems promising.

Answer (score -1):

yes your url mapping is wrong here in your case Remove below line from your controller to get output from url 2

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/files")
```

because you have give a url pattern at controller level so spring container first check url pattern at controller level 
if it find correct url pattern at controller then after it will search for any further url pattern

Here in your case

```
url 2. http://localhost:8080/dms/upload
```

will directly search for resource having url pattern starts with `upload` but spring container cant found the proper mapping
that why it wont give you desirable output

Comment: Are you really sure this is what OP expect ?What will happen now to URL `http://localhost:8080/dms/files/?module=abc` ?